# OrientDB Could not access the security JSON file

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

Following my upgrade from [OrientDB](http://orientdb.com/) `2.1.16` to `2.2.0` I have started to get the following messages during the initialisation:

```
2016-05-19 09:28:38:690 SEVER ODefaultServerSecurity.loadConfig() Could not access the security JSON file: /config/security.json [ODefaultServerSecurity]
2016-05-19 09:28:39:142 SEVER ODefaultServerSecurity.onAfterActivate() Configuration document is empty [ODefaultServerSecurity]
```

The database launched but I don't like the warnings. I've looked through the docs but I cant find anything specifically pertaining to this. There are some links on Google that lead to dead Github pages.

- First of all I need to get hold of either a copy of the `security.json` it is expecting (or the docs explaining the expected structure).
- Secondly I need to know how and where to set it.

Comment: are you sure 2.1.19?

Comment: Sorry... `2.1.16` :)

Comment: it should be in `config/` directory, I'm seeing it there in my installation. Don't you?

Comment: I'm actually running it as `plocal` embedded. I have just downloaded the independent application and found the `security.json`. I just need to know how to specify it during the embedded launch sequence.

Comment: I'm trying with embedded server and I got the same message

Comment: @IvanMainetti did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 ways to specify the location and name of the security.json file used by the new OrientDB security module.

1) Specify the environment variable, ORIENTDB_HOME, and it will look for it here:
"${ORIENTDB_HOME}/config/security.json"

2) Set this property in the orientdb-server-config.xml file: "server.security.file"

3) Pass the location by setting the global variable -Dserver.security.file on startup.

Here's the documentation on the new features + a link to the configuration format.

https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/Security-OrientDB-New-Security-Features.md

-Colin
OrientDB LTD
The Company behind OrientDB

Comment: Is there a way to programatically set it?
e.g. `ODefaultServerSecurity.setServerSecurityPath("path_to_security_file");`

Failing that with option 2: Where in the config file do I specify it? 
`<orient-server>
    ...
    <properties>
        <entry name="server.security.file" value="${path_to_security_file}" />
    </properties>
</orient-server>`

Comment: Sure.  Before you call OServer.create(), use System.setProperty("server.security.file", "...path...");

This does the same thing as passing in -Dserver.security.file.

Your orientdb-server-config.xml property entry will also work.

Comment: Can the use of security.json be disabled?